# WIFI turns off frequently on Windows 10 1903 10.0.18362.418 version

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, laptop, troubleshooting

I have had an issue with WIFI since 1903 version Windows 10 update (not sure exactly). After that WIFI started turning off in random moments.

I'm working on [Lenovo 320s 13-IKB](https://www.lenovo.com/pl/pl/laptops/ideapad/300-series/Ideapad-320S-13/p/88IP30S0902) with **Intel Dual Band Wireless AC-3165** module.

---

**I was trying to:**

- Update all drivers (even for BIOS) on Lenovo drivers page.
- Uncheck field in `Device manager > Intel Dual Band > Properties > Power management` to `Allow the comp to turn off...`
- Install another Windows 10 versions (after Anniversary update)

But these steps did not give me even a small chance to believe I will fix an issue.

---

Then I tried to install Ubuntu 18.04. But there WIFI was turning off too. I started thinking it's a physical problem with laptop. I went to the master and ask him to take a look at this problem and after that he said everything is OK with WIFI adapter. What the hack?! The antennas look connected. But this begs the question: **why it did not work on Ubuntu well?**

I was trying to connect to different WIFIs even in different countries, I was trying to change WIFI channel to the most unused but it didn't give me a positive result.

---

When it happens I have only two ways to fix it:

- Troubleshoot.
- Reboot laptop with disabling and then enabling WIFI in BIOS.

I can't relaod WIFI with that WIFI button in menu because it turns off and becomes unclickable.

[image]
[image]
[image]

---

**I hope someone has an answer how to fix it.** I really do not want to buy new WIFI adapter because it could still be a problem with 1903 Windows update. I read somewhere on Microsoft Update pages they have bug with old WIFI adapters... But I don't remember exactly what was it about.

**From my observations it DOES NOT depend on:**

- Operation System
- WIFI router
- Battery mode on laptop
  [image]

---

OK, I have just reconnect WIFI module to the laptop and it works! First week without that issue... I think I have fixed this problem.

## UPDATE

The same thing is repeating with 20H2 and 21H1 updates. I can assure the physical health of wifi module is fine. Hovewer, something is going on with Windows updates.

I have tried all possible version of drivers for Intel Dual Band Wireless AC-3165 but none of them helped me.

Imagine situation, every time I move my laptop from any point to another or just plugg it in, connect USB or whatever else the wifi is dissconecting with characteristic actions. I mean, the laptop lag for a few seconds and disallow me to even enter the Windows settings with WiFi tab.

Is there any possible solution to make it works correctly without waiting few weeks for new Windows update?

Comment: Check Windows Power Management that Wi-Fi is set for maximum performance and is not allowed to turn off. These are Windows settings (not Device Manager). Check Ubuntu Power options for the same settings.  Then finally, try a USB Wireless card. Set it up and see if it works.

Comment: @John, I have tried a High Performance and Balance mode (I have changed manually for Maximum WiFi performance). It doesn't help.

Comment: You need to try a USB Wireless card to see if that helps

Comment: @John yes, USB wireless adapter solves it. But how to fix integrated adapter? :( It is a problem with drivers compatibility?

Comment: That is an older Intel card (I think). I have an Intel 8260 on my Lenovo machine.  So if the USB card works, and the antennas are intact on the internal card (you checked this) then it seems time to upgrade the card

Comment: @John, probably u r right. But it's funny, because my usb adapter is much older than this laptop...

Comment: @K7AAY, can I just replace a new one with my old AC 3165? Or I need to check compatibility or smth else?

Comment: @entithat Here's what Intel is selling now. No idea if you can replace w/ old AC3165 
 https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/wireless/wireless-products.html

Comment: *"I went to the master and ask him to take a look at this problem and after that he said everything is OK with WIFI adapter."*  I'll bite:  who is "the master?"

Comment: Try installing the latest driver from Intel>>>>>>>https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/29088/Intel-Wireless-Bluetooth-for-Windows-10?product=89450

Comment: @Run5k, just an unofficial support center :)

Comment: 5 GHz wifi is far shorter range than 2.4 GHz wifi. Task Manager tells you signal strength on the performance tab.

Comment: @user1292580, I have 2.5Ghz wifi

Comment: and signal strength?

Comment: @user1292580, its not a problem with router at all. Because it have been working fine for a year before